# How is the Protection stat calculated?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've noticed a stat called **Protection** in the "Stats changed if equipped" tooltip that comes up when you hover over a piece of gear you aren't wearing

I know it's not just based on Armor value, since I've seen this value higher on pieces of armor that contain lower armor values, and see it on non-armor pieces such as rings and amulets too

I've also seen armor pieces that actually raise my armor when I equip them, but that have a negative Protection value compared to my current equipment.

So what does Protection take into account, and how is it calculated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Protection is a factor of the percent damage reduction that comes from both armor and the chance to dodge in order to show you which item will actually protect you better.

It takes into account

- Armor
- Strength (since armor is based on strength)
- Dodge Chance
- Dexterity (since dodge is based on dexterity)
- Any stats that increases armor or dodge chance from passive skills, such as the Monk's [Seize the Initiative](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/passive/seize-the-initiative) passive which adds the Monk's dexterity value to their armor value.

As of patch 1.0.3:

> Resist values will now be taken into effect when calculating the Protection comparison stat (the Protection value is an average protection estimate of all your resists)

However, this will not take the [Monk's One With Everything](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/passive/one-with-everything) Passive into account properly.  I found an item that would reportedly increase my Protection due to a difference in resistances, but in reality it decreases both my resistances and armor.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize it would take into account passive abilities and strength :)

Comment: I think it takes into account something else as well... I've found equipment that increases my armor, but lowers my protection. Perhaps it takes into account resistances too?

Comment: @rachel The other stat it factors in is Dodge.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz So it takes into account Armor, Strength, Dexterity (dodge), and any passives that affect armor values or dodge chance based on a stat the item gives? And does not consider resistances? You should post your own answer :)

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I hope you don't mind, but I edited your answer a bit to make it easier to read :)

Comment: @Rachel - No problem.  I should have done that from the beginning.