# What affixes does the comparison tooltip account for?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is the Protection stat calculated?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69197/how-is-the-protection-stat-calculated)

What affixes does the "Stat Changes if Equipped" section of a tooltip *not* take into account?

I would expect that the "Protection" value excludes elemental resistances as they are situational. Is this true, and are there any others? (In particular, what about "All Elements", since it affects all incoming damage?)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: As of the latest patch, protection takes resistances into account (maybe it's only if it's got "resistance to all" though).

Comment: You may want to throw a bounty on the original question, as your subquestion isn't quite answered, yet.

Comment: Bah, I searched like crazy before posting this question and *still* didn't see the dupe.